# Jsp custom tag issues

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I'm getting the following error when I try to run a jsp page with a custom jsp tag.

javax.servlet.ServletException: /pages/editBidForm.jsp(43,3) No tag "getName" defined in tag library imported with prefix "custom"
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:515)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
....
...

Here is my code(part) in the jsp page.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/taglib.tld" prefix="custom" %>
    <tr>

             <custom:getName name="Narayana Hari"/>

               </tr>
```

And the taglib.tld file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag 
Library 1.2//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">
<taglib>
      <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
      <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
      <shortname>custom</shortname>
  <tag>
      <name>hello</name>
      <tagclass>com.poran.action.CustomizedTag</tagclass>
      <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
      <info>Tag having no body</info>
      <attribute>
         <name>name</name>
         <required>true</required>
         <rtexpvalue>true</rtexpvalue>
      </attribute>
```

And the java class

```
package com.poran.action;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;

import java.util.*;

public class CustomizedTag implements Tag {
   private PageContext pageContext;
   private Tag parent;
   private String name;





   public String getName() {
    return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
   }

 /*  public CustomizedTag() {
      super();
   }
*/
   public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
  /*    try {
         pageContext.getOut().print(getName());
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
         throw new JspException("Error:"+ioe.getMessage());
      }*/
      return SKIP_BODY;
   }

   public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
      return SKIP_PAGE;
   }
   public void release() {
   }

public Tag getParent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void setPageContext(PageContext arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setParent(Tag arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

  /* public void setPageContext(PageContext pageContext) {
      this.pageContext = pageContext;
   }

   public void setParent(Tag parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
   }

   public Tag getParent() {
      return parent;
   }*/

}
```

Please suggest me where to correct.

Thanks,
Aditya R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only tag you have defined in your taglib (looking at your code) is "hello". How about you try to change it to `<name>getName</name>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had not understood the tags properly. That solved my problem. :)